# batch file to set attrib +r on all .docx files created or modified in the last days

Tags: batch-file

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to utilise a batch script to modify the attributes of all .docx files in a given folder to +R when a field is changed within an access database.

getting the script to run is the easy bit.

I currently set attrib +R on *.docx - which is fine as there are only around 300 files in the folder, however this will grow very, very rapidly.

I've considered having new files created in a different directory, then use robocopy to move them on an event in access, but the event will have to be when creating the hyperlink to the document - the file cannot be moved at that stage.

Is there a way to efficiently set +R on directories with a large number of files, the majority of which will already be +R?

Either by checking modified / created date not greater than say 7 days, or checking the files that already have +R?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to face it via `forfiles`, `dir`, `robocopy`, ...  but all of them have the same problem: to determine what files needs to be processed, all of them need to be checked.

Using `dir` to search the needed files and `attrib` to change its attributes

```dos
pushd "x:\where\files\are" && (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-r-d *.docx') attrib +r "%%a"
    popd
)
```

Using `robocopy` to do all the work

```dos
pushd "x:\where\files\are" && (
    robocopy . . /is /XA:R /A+:R /COPY:A
    popd
)
```

In both cases only files without the read only attribute will be processed. The `robocopy` command should be faster as only one executable is started while the `for / dir` solution needs to execute `attrib` for each found file, but `robocopy` is only directly included in the OS since Vista (for XP or 2003 it can be downloaded from Microsoft)